# Providing a large number of inputs to a function

Tags: r, function

I have a large number of naive models fitted to different time series. How can I pass these models into a function?

```r
for(i in i:10){
  ts <- ts(seq(i, i+20, 1), frequency = 12)
  name <- paste("fit_", i, sep = "")
  assign(name, naive(ts))
}
```

I need to define a function like below, but I don't want to write all of the model names separately.

```r
example_func <- function(fit_1,fit_2,...){}
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps put them in a list, and then pass the list to your function?

Comment: It worked, thank you!